# formtastic nested form creating wrong path for action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, formtastic

I have a rails app with 3 models something like:

[image: has_many_through]

I'm trying to create a form to edit the join table (eg. change the appointment_date in the example model):

```
1 <%= semantic_form_for [:active_admin, :organization, @organization_membership] do |f| %>
2   <%= f.inputs "Organization" do %>
3     <h2><%= @organization_membership.organization.name %></h2>
4     <% @organization_membership.organization.organization_memberships.each do |organization_member| %>
5       <%= organization_member.user.name %></br>
6     <% end %>
7   <% end %>
8   <%= f.inputs "New Member" do %>
9     <span id="new-member"></span>
10     <% if !resource.user.nil? %>
11       <h3><%= resource.user.login %></h3>
12     <% end %>
13     <%= f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :id => 'user-id' } %>
14     <%= f.input :organization_id, :as => :hidden, :value => @organization_membership.organization.id %>
15     <%= f.input :start_date, :as => :date_picker %>
16     <%= f.input :end_date,   :as => :date_picker %>
17   <% end %>
18   <%= f.actions %>
19 <% end %>
```

The problem is that this renders a page with the following html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8"
      action        ="/active_admin/organizations/8/organization_memberships/8"
      class         ="formtastic organization_membership"
      id            ="edit_organization_membership_8"
      method        ="post"
      novalidate    ="novalidate">
```

The problem is the `action`. It's should look like this:

```
/active_admin/organizations/:organization_id/organization_membership/organization_membership_id
```

But, instead of `:organization_id`, formtastic is putting in the `organization_membership_id`. I suspect that my problem is in the top line `<%= semantic_form_for [:active_admin, :organization, @organization_membership]`.

EDIT: I've managed to get this "working" by extending the `update()` method with the following ugly hack:

```
def update
    params[:organization_id] = params[:organization_membership][:organization_id]                                                                            
    super
end
```

Still searching for a real solution to this problem.

Comment: Its possible that the two have same value?  Have you verified this?

Comment: They do not. The edit page is at `/active_admin/organizations/2/organization_memberships/8/edit`. I've even checked `params[:organization_id]` and it is set to 2.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the problem here is with the following line

> "<%= semantic_form_for [:active_admin, :organization, @organization_membership]"

For nested resources, you will need to explicitly pass an organization object. For example:

```
def edit
    @organization = Organization.find(id)
end
```

and then in the view, you need to make a slight correction:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:active_admin, @organization , @organization_membership] do |f| %>
```

You must pass the organization as a resource and not as a symbol.
You can find more about it in the formtastic docs.(Look for nested resources under usage section.)